# Firebase Admin Token is being generated with invalid signature

Tags: node.js, firebase, parse-platform, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have created an App using the Parse server, and have now decided to implement some aspects of firebase into my app. Im trying to accomplish this by doing the signInWithCustomToken method in swift on ios. Im calling a rest service to generate a firebase token, and then signing in with that token returned upon valid sign in on my current auth system. However, the token being generated appears to have an invalid signature when pasting it into jwt.io. The environment that im using is node based (inside the parse server). It seems very simple and i have followed the firebase instrucutions/poured over questions on this over the last few days and im really not sure what im doing wrong! Heres my rest service on how i generate the token, i initialize the server with this method:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("initServer", function(request, response){
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

    var serviceAccount = require('/home/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/firebase/serviceAccountKey.json');
    console.log(serviceAccount);
    admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            databaseURL: 'https://urabo-acb7a.firebaseio.com'
    });

    response.success("Server Init OK");

});
```

this is the post method i call to generate the token from firebase-admin sdk:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("generateFirebaseToken", function(request, response) {

    var admin = require('firebase-admin');



    admin.auth().createCustomToken(request.params.uid)
    .then(function(customToken) {
    // Send token back to client
       response.success(customToken);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
    });


});
```

And of course I went into the firebase console and generated the private key, and then scp'd it over to my server. Im not really sure why this is not working, it generates a token it just doesnt appear to be valid or linked to my account. Am i missing some weird encoding issue or something with the token? Does anyone have insight on this?? Thanks so much!

Comment: These tokens only validate against Google's public keys. These can be obtained from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com but I don't know how to specify them to jwt.io. You should just try to sign in using a custom token. That is the most straightforward way to determine if a token is valid or not. Here's an example from Admin SDK integration tests: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/test/integration/auth.spec.ts#L281

Answer (score 1):

—The main question is are your users signing in to the REST service through your app and then you are also trying to re-authenticate them again with the token generated in your system?

—If they will be accessing further REST functions once authenticated, then why not authenticate them successfully when 'a' token is returned?

—Usually token usage or handling is restricted by the API providers. Another option is instead of involving user auth directly with the API service, have a separate auth system — the usual SignIn process and then make API calls based on the requested API feature. That way your app is interacting with the APIs and users remain at the front end.

Comment: Basically, a user logs in through my existing auth service in Parse. Once authenticated I call a rest service to generate a firebase token so that they can also authenticate with firebase services (I want to implement firebase chat with out completely swapping out my auth system for firebase). I can return this token when the user signs in successfully, but am just testing with the token for now to see that it’s valid as that appears to be the issue.